# Uploading Binaries to Maven Repository

Tags: maven, repository

Is it possible to upload binaries (like war file) to maven repository. Also I need to download this to any remote system. Is there any client for this?
Can anyone help me...

Thanks
Saumya

Comment: You can upload files like war, ear etc. which is created by a Maven build and you can use that by Maven or you can download those artifacts by a simple curl command....

Comment: take a look at repository managers such as JFrog Artifactory or Nexus